# How can I make a samba share read/write for all users?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

I'm trying to mount a samba share in ubuntu, however I can't seem to make it read/write for other users (I can read write to it fine).

This is the fstab entry:

```
//10.0.0.1/storage/dumps /media/dumps cifs _netdev,guest,uid=1000,gid=1001,iocharset=utf8,fmask=777,dmask=777,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777,umask=000,rw,user,exec,codepage=unicode,unicode 0 0
```

where gid=1001 is the smb share group (I created) and uid=1000 is me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

- Put your credentials in `fstab`, using the `credentials=/path/to/credfile` mount option. The file must contain your username and password in two separate lines. **All users will connect as the same SMB account.**
- True multi-user mounts can be done with the `multiuser` option; however, this requires Kerberos security to be used (`sec=krb5i`, `krb5p`, `krb5`), since the kernel cannot prompt users for credentials.

  <sub>(It *may* be possible to use PAM and kernel keyrings to store the password on login, but so far this is just an idea, and it would be more complicated and less convenient than Kerberos.)</sub>

Comment: Im connecting as guest so login shouldnt be needed